# Number of positive divisors of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, repunit-numbers

Prove that the number of positive divisors of 1992 1s: $111...1$ is even.

I have no idea tackling this question. Can anyone provide any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Try to figure out which numbers have an odd number of divisors. Then it's easy to see that the given is not one of them.

Comment: perfect squares have odd number of divisors?

Comment: Are there others?

Comment: No, i got a question proving the statement: N is perfect square iff N has odd number of positive divisors

Comment: Good. So why is $$\frac{10^{1992}-1}{9}$$ not a perfect square?

Comment: Hint: look at this number modulo $3$ and modulo $9$.

Comment: God! i haven't studied anything about modulo, I found this question in a combinatorics book(wondering why such question will appear in combinatorics books), but thanks for the information. I will carry it on from here!

Comment: For what particular topics should I consult in number theory book? Can you point out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $k$ is a divisor of $n$, $\frac{n}{k}$ is also a divisor of $n$. In other words, the positive divisors of a number *come in pairs*. That means all numbers have an even number of positive divisors *unless $k=\frac{n}{k}$*. Because if $k$ does equal $\frac{n}{k}$, you discard one of them from your count. You don't count the same thing twice.

If you have understood everything up to this point, you should realize that *a number can have an odd number of positive divisors if and only if it is a perfect square.*

Now you just have to show that your number is not a perfect square and you're done!

This is not difficult to do, because any perfect square is $\equiv 0, 1 \pmod 4$. And your number is $\equiv 3\pmod 4$. So it can't be a perfect square.

So it has to have an even number of positive divisors.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The number of divisors of primes is even (equals to $2$). The number of divisors of $4$ is odd ($\{1,2,4\}$). The number of divisors of $6$ is even ($\{1,2,3,6\}$). The number of divisors of $8$ is even ($\{1,2,4,8\}$). The number of divisors of $9$ is odd. The number of divisors of $10,12,14,15$ is even. The number of divisors of $16$ is odd.

Can you see a pattern?

Comment: Are you implying that perfect square has odd number of divisors while other don't?

Comment: Maybe. Do you have an idea why that would be true?

Comment: The prime factorisation of a perfect square shows that it can only have odd number of positive divisors?

Comment: Does it? You can try to prove it, but maybe try thinking about it this way: the divisors of a number always appear in pairs.

Comment: I did prove it in an previous exercise, which is the statement that N is perfect square iff N has odd number of positive divisors by using the decomposition of N into its prime, but I find your method interesting, that the divisors of a number always appear in pairs!

Comment: Well, they don't always. The number $4$ has no pair among the divisors of $16$.